# Symfony 4.1.6 Could not find any fixture services to load

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to create fixtures for my Symfony project. Unfortunately I'm plagued with the following error:

> In LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php line 95:
>
> Could not find any fixture services to load.

I have tried everything people suggested here. But no help.

My code is this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Users;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $encoder;

    private function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder){
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = new Users();
        $user->setUsername('wessel');
        $user->setPassword(
            $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, '123abc')
        );
        $user->setEmail('test@test.te');

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

I have triend editing the services.yaml aswell, i added:

```
  App\DataFixtures\:
        resource: '../src/DataFixtures'
        tags: [doctrine.fixture.orm]
```

Unfortunately no help, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Remove that stuff you added to services.yaml, your fixtures are autowired automatically, no need for that block.

Comment: I already removed it, i tried to test if it worked.

Comment: Is your fixture file in the correct folder?

Comment: The fixture is in the automatically generated file:
- src / DataFixtures / UserFixtures.php

Comment: Can you please add a complete console output , when you let a single PhpUnit test run?

Comment: Maybe this one helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159781/symfony-4-how-to-load-datafixtures-in-a-kerneltestcase/51171253#51171253

Answer (score 0):

Beware that with lastest **HauteLook AliceBundle fixtures**, the command to load fixtures is now :

`php bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load`

Using *php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load* will result in a `Could not find any fixture services to load.` error

Additionally, when the command fails to purge the database, you can use

```
php bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```